# How do I format and load a 4D-array in R?

Tags: python, arrays, r, formatting, dataset

For example, the following code loads the CIFAR10 dataset into R, where x_train is a 4D array.

```
# Loads CIFAR10 data
cifar10 <- dataset_cifar10()
c(c(x_train, y_train), c(x_test, y_test)) %<-% cifar10

dim(x_train)
[1] 50000   32   32    3
```

How do I design my dataset to be loaded here instead of the CIFAR10?

P.S - Is there a way to load a 4D numpy array created using Python, in R? I have so far found only support for until 2D arrays.

Comment: How are you connecting R and python?  Is it R from python or python from R?   If it is the former, use either `rpy2` or `pyper` and for the latter reticulate.  with pyper, you can assign objects in to R workspace, apply the algorithms on the data and then get the output into python.  Not clear about the architecture

Comment: I actually am looking for a solution where I don't have to connect them both, since I am more familiar with R. Thank you, will look into 'rpy2' and 'pyper'.

Comment: Maybe you can workaround by simply exporting the 4d numpy array as a 1d array and then import and reshape in R.

Comment: Can you direct me on how to do that?